# Compare value of previous row

Tags: php

I have a database of jobs and interpreters. I am trying to make a table for each interpreter to see their jobs for the upcoming week, but I'm having trouble sorting them. Right now it keeps putting each job into a different table but what I want is for it to keep it in the same table for each interpreter ordered by first_name and then end the table and create a NEW table for the next interpreter. I thought maybe I could make some kind of variable that stores the value of the previous row and then ends the table with `echo "</table>";`
 but I haven't figured out how. I figure if I can finally get them to group, I can eventually put the html table into an email. The sql is a saved view that has it ordered by first_name already but also returns a value for inter_id (even though that part isn't shown in the table). I was thinking I could compare the value of inter_id on each row. This is what I've got right now:

```
$table_start="

 <table style=\"width:100%\">
 <tr>
 <th>Date & Time</th>
 <th>Interpreter</th>
     <th>Subject</th>
     <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
 ";
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {


    /* fetch associative array */
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $outcome_id=$row['outcome_id'];
    $inter_id=$row['inter_id'];
    $start = $row['start'];
    $beginning = hr_datetime($start); //this function is elsewhere
    echo $table_start;

    echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
    echo $beginning;

    echo "</td>";
    if ($cur_inter_id === NULL){
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<font color=\"red\">"; //I want it obvious someone is not assigned
        echo "<b>"; //bold
        echo "NOT";
        echo "&nbsp";
        echo "ASSIGNED";
        echo "</font>";
        echo "</b>";
        echo "</td>";


    }    else {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['First_Name'];
        echo "&nbsp";
        echo $row['Last_Name'];
        echo "</td>";


    }


    echo "<td>";
    if ($outcome_id === '9'){echo "<strike> <font color=\"orange\"> <b>";} //I want it to be obvious an app is cancelled,


    echo $row['subject'];
    if ($outcome_id === '9'){echo "/CANCELLED </strike></font></b>";}

    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['location'];
    echo "</td>";




    }



}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: presumably you don't think the sql is important to answer this but the chances are that much of the work could be done in the sql query?

Comment: you do not want to echo `$table_start` in a loop

Comment: If you haven't yet figured out the significance of the last comment I made - let me explain. If you echo the variable `$table_start` in the loop but close the table outside the loop you will generate an ungodly mess of invalid html. Echo that variable `once`  immediately before the loop begins! That is why it appears that `it keeps putting each job into a different table `

Comment: First, a small tip: use single quote for strings in PHP when putting HTML in those strings, that is: `echo '<font color="red">';` - that way you don't have to escape the double quotes of the html attributes inside the string.

Comment: I didn't see the use in putting in the sql because I couldn't see any way to make this happen with only one sql query. And I figured doing a bunch of separate sql queries would be inefficient and odd. But the view is:  $sql = "select * from next_week_with_contacts_sorted";

Comment: SELECT Appointment.start, Appointment.jobID, Appointment.inter_id, Appointment.subject, Appointment.location,
Appointment.outcome_id, Appointment.region, Appointment.language, Interpreters.First_Name, Interpreters.Last_Name
FROM Appointment
left join  Interpreters on Appointment.inter_id = Interpreters.inter_id
WHERE YEARWEEK(start) = YEARWEEK(NOW(0),0)+1
and outcome_id < 9
ORDER by Interpreters.First_Name, START

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the comment above for explanation of why the results appeared in different tables - here is just a tidied up version that should render the table correctly at least. The css should be defined elsewhere - try not to use inline style definitions if you can.

```
if( $result = $conn->query( $sql ) ) {

    echo '
        <style>
            table{width:100%}
            .bold{font-weight:bold}
            .red{color:red}
            .orange{color:orange}
            .green{color:green}
        </style>


        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Date & Time</th>
                <th>Interpreter</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>';


    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {

        $inter_id=$row['inter_id'];
        $start=$row['start'];

        $interpreter = is_null( $cur_inter_id ) ? "<span class='bold red'>NOT ASSIGNED</span>" : sprintf( '%s %s', $row['First_Name'], $row['Last_Name'] );
        $subject=intval( $row['outcome_id'] )==9 ? "<span class='bold orange'>CANCELLED</span>" : "<span class='green'>OK</span>";

        printf('
                <tr>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                </tr>',
                hr_datetime( $start ),
                $interpreter,
                $subject,
                $row['location']
        );
    }//end loop

    echo '
        <table>';

}//end if
```

Comment: I think the issue was that each job was in a separate table whereas they want *I am trying to make a table for each interpreter*.  So I assume the SQL returns multiple interpreters and each should be in it's own table with all the jobs for them together.

Comment: to be fair I found it hard to understand the actual question but picked up on the obvious error. It would have been nice had we been able to see the sql rather than guessing though.

Comment: Yeah, I had the table start outside the loop but that just kept putting everything in the same table. Putting it inside the loop gave me separate tables, but it still separated each individual job into a separate table whereas what I'm aiming for is to have each table grouped into each interpreter's jobs. That's why it was inside the loop. So one table per interpreter so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I second everything @RamRaider has written. Especially with respect to the way you format your table.

However, I prepared a little fiddle on the basis of your original script to demonstrate the point of *how to create individual tables for each interpreter*:

```
$prev_id="start";
echo $table_start;
foreach ($dat as $row){ // (this emulates the database)

  $outcome_id=$row['outcome_id'];
  $inter_id=$row['inter_id'];
  $cur_inter_id=$inter_id;
  $start = $row['start'];
  $beginning = $start; //  hr_datetime($start); //this function is elsewhere
  // ============================================================================
  // compare the current ID with the previous one and create table division here:
  if ($prev_id!="start" && $inter_id!=$prev_id) echo "</table>\n\n".$table_start;
  // ============================================================================

  echo"\n<tr>";
      echo "<td>";
  echo $beginning;

  echo "</td>";
  if ($cur_inter_id === NULL){
      echo "<td>";
      echo "<font color=\"red\">"; //I want it obvious someone is not assigned
      echo "<b>"; //bold
      echo "NOT";
      echo "&nbsp";
      echo "ASSIGNED";
      echo "</font>";
      echo "</b>";
      echo "</td>";
  }   else {
      echo "<td>";
      echo $row['First_Name'];
      echo "&nbsp";
      echo $row['Last_Name'];
      echo "</td>";
  }

  echo "<td>";
  if ($outcome_id == '9'){echo "<strike><font color=\"orange\"> <b>";} //I want it to be obvious an app is cancelled,

  echo $row['subject'];
  if ($outcome_id == '9'){echo "/CANCELLED </font></strike></b>";}

  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo $row['location'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

  $prev_id=$inter_id;
}
echo "</table>";
```

See the demo here: https://rextester.com/WNAOTN55281

Comment: I think you've picked up on what I was wanting. My previous attempts were close to this but I had become frustrated. I'll test this out soon. Thanks